# equation displays "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Int'"

Tags: swift, string, integer

I'm trying to display a number on a label that is calculated by values entered in a textfield box. However, I am getting this error where I am trying to do the equation. My code is below. Any idea what I need to change to allow it to display that answer?

```
 func calculateRewardPoints() -> Int {
            if currentLevelStepper.value == 1 {
                
                resultHeaderLabel.text = "60 Required Forge Points for Lvl 1"
              
                rewardLinkOne.text = "10"
                rewardLinkTwo.text = "5"
                rewardLinkThree.text = "0"
                rewardLinkFour.text = "0"
                rewardLinkFive.text = "0"
    
                var roundone =  round(((Double(bonusinput.isTextNumber().1) + Double(100)) / Double(100) ) * Double(10) )
                var roundtwo =  round(((Double(bonusinput.isTextNumber().1) + Double(100)) / Double(100) ) * Double(5) )
                var roundthree =  round(((Double(bonusinput.isTextNumber().1) + Double(100)) / Double(100) ) * Double(5) )
                var roundfour =  round(((Double(bonusinput.isTextNumber().1) + Double(100)) / Double(100) ) * Double(5) )
                var roundfive =  round(((Double(bonusinput.isTextNumber().1) + Double(100)) / Double(100) ) * Double(5) )
                
                rateRewardLinkOne.text = String(roundone)
                rateRewardLinkTwo.text = String(roundtwo)
                rateRewardLinkThree.text = String(roundthree)
                rateRewardLinkFour.text = String(roundfour)
                rateRewardLinkFive.text = String(roundfive)
              
                
                
                //rateRewardLinkFive.text = String(  ( (Double(bonusinput.isTextNumber().1) + Double(100)) / Double(100) ) * Double(5) )
    
              
       
                fpSecureLinkOne.text = "40"
                fpSecureLinkTwo.text = "40"
                fpSecureLinkThree.text = "45"
                fpSecureLinkFour.text = "45"
                fpSecureLinkFive.text = "45"
                
                
    /*(A)*/       var totalfp = 60
    /*(B)*/       var fpadded = String(Int(fpinput.isTextNumber().1))
    /*(C1)*/      var baserewardone = 10
    /*(C2)*/      var baserewardtwo = 5
    /*(C3)*/      var baserewardthree = 0
    /*(C4)*/      var baserewardfour = 0
    /*(c5)*/      var baserewardfive = 0
            
    /*(D)*/       var arcbonus = ((bonusinput.isTextNumber().1) + 100) / 100
                  var squaredone = (baserewardone * arcbonus) * 2
                  var squaredtwo = (baserewardtwo * arcbonus) * 2
                  var squaredthree = (baserewardthree * arcbonus) * 2
                  var squaredfour = (baserewardfour * arcbonus) * 2
                  var squaredfive = (baserewardfive * arcbonus) * 2
                
                
                var securefpthree = 45
                var securefpfour = 45
                var securefpfive = 45
                
// Where error occurs      // I need the fpSecure labels to be  ( (A-B) - ((C*D)*2) ) 
                fpSecureLinkOne.text = String((totalfp - fpadded) - squaredone)
                
            }
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with swift, but it looks like calculateRewardPoints returns an int, and you are returning a string. So if you want to return a string: "calculateRewardPoints() -> String" or if you want to return an int: don't cast fpSecureLinkOne to a string. I think you want the former ("-> String") if you want to display the calculation result.

Comment: Yeah, I need to display the Int as a 'string' on the label

Comment: Ok, so I think the first line should read "func calculateRewardPoints() -> String {"

Answer (score 0):

This is called string interpolation

```
"\(your number)"
```

Comment: I put my equation in there and it still gives me that error.

Comment: in function signature you set to return an Int, and you are returning nothing as I see. What should happen here? what are you trying to do? you are setting label values in function that returns some integer? why? can you explain purpose of the func?